# Page navigation development

Tags: javascript, url, visual-web-developer, bem

- I wanted to understand how do the page navigation on BEM website (http://getbem.com/introduction/) without refreshing the window. I wanted to know, the development of the calling different URLs without refreshing the page.
  Please help me understand this type of page navigation.

Comment: you can study the source code of the page using your browser's developer tools in order to understand how it works. But in general, this kind of thing is achieved using JavaScript and possibly also AJAX (depending if the content is loaded from the remote server each time, or just shown and hidden in the existing page). There are a few different ways such a thing could be done.

Comment: i am just referring the same site for example purpose. Wanted to know the way the page navigation is taking place on the particular site.

Comment: I tried checking the sorce code. I believe the pages are being called from server end or something. But how without refreshing the page. Also, the URl is refreshing as well.

Comment: I gave you two possible ways already. If you don't know what words like AJAX mean, it's time to do some research and studying. By the way, it's also possible to change the URL using Javascript without actually navigating anywhere.